# How can I reformulate this multiplicative model as a linear model?

Tags: r, linear-model

I want to fit this models

$$
Y \sim D(μ, σ) \\
μ = X1 * (β1 + β2 * X2)
$$

(D is probably Gamma)

Y is 0 when X1 is 0, but the slope depends linearly on X2.

I can fit something close with the R formula `Y ~ 0+X1:X2_c`, where `X2_c` is a categorized version of X2, but I want to model it continuously.

(Sorry for the informative title, but I do not know what to call this type of model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula

$$
\mu = X1 * (\beta 1 + \beta 2 * X2)
$$

Is equivalent to

$$
\mu = \beta 1*X1 + \beta 2 * X1 * X2
$$

So I would propose creating a new variable, $X3 = X1 * X2$. Then you can use a typical R formula like `Y ~ 0 + X1 + X3`.

Comment: Of course! This works perfectly.